# Facebook's alternatives to liking

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

When I use Facebook I can see buttons:

- Like
- Love
- Haha
- Wow
- Sad
- Angry

Are the alternatives to liking the same for everyone using Facebook (in every region, in every device)?

"Confused" one day vanished. What happened to it?

I saw some news articles that included "Yay". How come I don't have "Yay"?

Comment: Available in Ireland and Spain right now I think - it may be going world wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Verge: Facebook's Like button will soon have these emoticon alternatives, says report](http://www.theverge.com/2015/10/8/9477729/facebook-reactions-like-button-emoji)

Facebook is testing alternatives to the Like button. The key word here is: "testing".

I'm sure they're doing A/B testing to see what works best. It doesn't surprise me at all that some have changed or disappeared. They're testing it, after all.

The test was originally set for Ireland and Spain and from what I can see has not expanded to other countries. I also don't see any sort of announcement as to when they might end the testing or roll this out more widely.